# Limit of difference

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics

From the difference calculus, I'm looking for conditions that delineate the class of functions $f(x)$ for which $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Delta_1^n f(x)=0$. Thanks.

Comment: can you precise the notation $\Delta_1^n$, is it $f(x+1)-f(x)$, applied $n$ times ?

Comment: $\Delta_h^n x^r=\frac{(-1)^n}{h^n}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(x+k h)^r$

Comment: $\Delta_1^1 f(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$, $\Delta_h^2 f(x)=\Delta_h^1(\Delta_h^1 f(x))$, etc.